# Format document library JSON for URL buttons

Tags: sharepoint-online

I'm not sure when but SharePoint changed the icon for URLs. Now our document library view looks like this and the buttons are not selectable:

https://imgur.com/7hxijol

How can we update our JSON code to fix this issue?

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/tile-formatting.schema.json",
  "height": 100,
  "width": 260,
  "hideSelection": true,
  "fillHorizontally": true,
  "formatter": {
    "elmType": "button",
    "attributes": {
      "class": "sp-card-container",
      "href": "[$FileRef]"
    },
    "customRowAction": {
      "action": "defaultClick"
    },
    "style": {
      "min-width": "254px",
      "width": "254px",
      "cursor": "pointer",
      "border": "none",
      "background-color": "transparent"
    },
    "children": [
      {
        "elmType": "div",
        "attributes": {
          "class": "sp-card-defaultClickButton"
        },
        "customRowAction": {
          "action": "defaultClick"
        }
      },
      {
        "elmType": "div",
        "attributes": {
          "class": "ms-bgColor-white sp-css-borderColor-neutralLight sp-card-borderHighlight sp-card-subContainer"
        },
        "children": [
          {
            "elmType": "div",
            "attributes": {
              "class": "sp-card-previewColumnContainer"
            },
            "children": [
              {
                "elmType": "div",
                "attributes": {
                  "class": "sp-card-imageContainer"
                },
                "style": {
                  "max-height": "90px",
                  "max-width": "75px",
                  "min-height": "90px",
                  "min-width": "75px",
                  "display": "flex",
                  "align-items": "stretch",
                  "justify-content": "bottom"
                },
                "children": [
                  {
                    "elmType": "filepreview",
                    "attributes": {
                      "src": "@thumbnail.512x432"
                    },
                    "customRowAction": {
                      "action": "defaultClick"
                    },
                    "style": {
                      "max-height": "90px",
                      "max-width": "75px",
                      "min-height": "90px",
                      "min-width": "75px"
                    },
                    "filePreviewProps": {
                      "fileTypeIconClass": "sp-fileTypeIcon-cardDesigner",
                      "brandTypeIconClass": "sp-brandTypeIcon-cardDesigner"
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "elmType": "div",
            "style": {
              "text-align": "left",
              "margin-left": "80px",
              "margin-right": "5px"
            },
            "children": [
              {
                "elmType": "div",
                "attributes": {
                  "class": "sp-card-defaultClickButton"
                },
                "customRowAction": {
                  "action": "defaultClick"
                },
                "style": {
                  "white-space": "wrap",
                  "word-break": "keep-all",
                  "flex": "1",
                  "width": "160px",
                  "max-height": "254px",
                  "margin-top": "-85px",
                  "font-size": "12px",
                  "color": "#243746"
                },
                "txtContent": "[$AssetType]",
                "defaultHoverField": "[$FileLeafRef]"
              },
              {
                "elmType": "div",
                "attributes": {
                  "class": "sp-card-defaultClickButton"
                },
                "customRowAction": {
                  "action": "defaultClick"
                },
                "style": {
                  "weight": "Bold",
                  "white-space": "wrap",
                  "word-break": "keep-all",
                  "flex": "1",
                  "width": "160px",
                  "max-height": "254px",
                  "margin-top": "-68px"
                },
                "txtContent": "[$FileLeafRef]",
                "defaultHoverField": "[$FileLeafRef]"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```